# how to kill parent and child process through shell?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, fork, parent-child

I have an application which is initiated by the shell and terminated by the shell. Now in my application I had created a fork to reduce the load of my application so currently two processes running on same name with different PID's. Now I want to terminate my program, and if I kill with the PID of my process in shell it only kills the parent process leaving it as a zombie process and the child process remains. So how to kill both child and parent processes through the shell?

Comment: I think you can use a negative PID....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the command [`killall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall).

Comment: if i can able to use kill -9 processname in terminal but i can't use in shell or in my application ,because my application i have one child process that child process has the another child process ,so i want to kill second child in my application,and kill the first child in shell ,or kill the parent process ,if it possible to kill like this manner

Answer (score 2):

do `ps -el` you will get the following

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
```

get `pid` and `ppid` of your process do `pkill -P <parent_pid_name>` meaning your parent process id which has spawned children and followed by `kill <signal number> <pid>` In this case too, in place of `pid` you have to give the parent process id who has spawned all the children .

Answer (score 1):

Your father process should trap SIGTERM and kill its child before exit.

I wrote this in C

```
int child;

void sighandler(int sig) {
        if (sig == SIGTERM) {
                if (child != -1) kill(child, SIGTERM);
        }
}

int main() {
        int i;

        child = -1;
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
        signal(SIGTERM, sighandler);

        setsid();
        setpgid(0,0);

        i = fork();
        switch(i) {
        case -1:
                break;
        case 0: // child
                sleep (100);
                break;
        default:
                child = i;
                sleep (100);
                break;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

You can kill all processes with the same name with the "killall" command.

Answer (score 0):

pkill command you can use to kill process. Also killall